# Ionic 4 wait for async method return

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I have an Ionic 4 application where I can get the users list with the `"cloud" service (http).`
The `cloud.getRemoteAccessUsers` is an `asynchronous` method, but I can't edit in the service.
I want create a guard for check user exist, I will paste a code snippet.

I want if the `console.log(test)` is show an array, but is only return with `ZoneAwarePromise`.

```js
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    this.lock = this.cloud.getLocks().find(x => +x.Id === +route.paramMap.get('id'));

    let test = this.cloud.getRemoteAccessUsers(this.lock).then((data) => {
        return data;
    });

    console.log(test);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: can you please share console log also and what you want to get print also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) interface can also return a `Promise<boolean>` or `Observable<boolean>`

You can return your observable directly:

```js
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    this.lock = this.cloud.getLocks().find(x => +x.Id === +route.paramMap.get('id'));

    return this.cloud.getRemoteAccessUsers(this.lock).then((data) => {
        return data;
    });
}
```

If `data` isn't a boolean, you can write the logic in the `callback` to return a `boolean`.

Your current log for test will show `ZoneAwarePromise` because it's an async call, so you are logging the `promise` and not the value that the `promise` returns.

If its the value you want, you can either log the `data` inside the `.then`

```js
return test = this.cloud.getRemoteAccessUsers(this.lock).then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    return data;
});
```

You could also use `async/await`:

```js
async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    this.lock = this.cloud.getLocks().find(x => +x.Id === +route.paramMap.get('id'));

    const test = await this.cloud.getRemoteAccessUsers(this.lock);
    console.log(test);
    return test;
}
```

Comment: This is the answer. Your code has a minor error though: You forgot to delete the variable name after return. Also, you can delete your then block as it effectively does nothing. `return this.cloud.getRemoteAccessUsers(this.lock);`. Additionally, you have to change the method return type to `Promise<boolean>`, as it is not returning a plain `boolean` anymore.

Comment: @pascalpuetz thanks! good catch .. also agree on your comment, though i dont like to edit too much so it doesnt confuse the OP

Comment: The last code is worked with boolean changed to Promise<boolean> and returned with a statement. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return `Promise`, but not the data

If you want to resolve `Promise` right inside the `CanActivate` method, then move your `test` assignment inside `then`.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        this.lock = this.cloud.getLocks().find(x => +x.Id === +route.paramMap.get('id'));

        this.cloud.getRemoteAccessUsers(this.lock).then((data) => {
           let test = data;
           console.log(test);
        });

        return false;
 }
```

Comment: Yes, it's working, but I want check the "test" variable out of the "then". How can I do it?

Comment: Using `async-await` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59459156/ionic-4-wait-for-async-method-return/59459238#59459238)